# JUnit5 - Showcase test case name dynamically from json file

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I want to display test case name dynamically on running the test cases using Junit5..so please help me on that

```
@ParameterizedTest
@JsonFileSource(resouce="file1.json")
public void abcTest(JsonObje obj){
}

file1.json
[{
"test-case-name" : "test case for infant",
"ageGroup" : "infant"
},
{
"test-case-name" : "test case for adult",
"ageGroup" : "adult"
},
{
"test-case-name" : "test case for mature",
"ageGroup" : "mature"
}
]

I want to display test case name dynamically on running the test cases using Junit5..
For example ... :

test case for infant
test case for adult
test case for mature
...
```

I want to display test case name dynamically on running the test cases using Junit5..
For example

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much information, but I believe that you want [JUnit's Dynamic Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests), instead of parameterized tests.

```
@TestFactory
Collection<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromCollection() {
  JsonArray array = ...
  List<DynamicTest> tests = new ArrayList<>();
  for (JsonObject testCase: array) {
    String testCaseName = testCase.get("test-case-name");
    String ageGroup = testCase.get("age-group");
    tests.add(DynamicTest.dynamicTest(testCaseName, () -> testAbc(ageGroup)));
  }
  return tests;
}
```

This will create a unit test for each of your age groups.

Comment: Right but the answer what you gave is not the one what I am looking for. I need to extract test-case name from json file and apply dynamically on method name abcTest while executing it dynamically it will be displayed test case name, that kind of solution I am looking for though thank you.- @Olivier Grégoire